# Can't write to StorageMap when benchmarking, EncodeLike is not implemented for any type even if it's the same in pallet

Tags: benchmarking, benchmark

I have the following `StorageMap` defined in my pallet:

```
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type Signatures<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    T::Hash,
    BoundedBTreeMap<Public, BoundedVec<u8, T::SignatureLength>, T::MaxAuthorities>,
>;
```

and in the benchmarks:

```
benchmarks!{
test_add{
    type CustomMap= BoundedBTreeMap<sp_core::sr25519::Public, BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<64>>, ConstU32<32>>;
        let mut custom : CustomMap= BoundedBTreeMap::new();
        let id = H256::default();// using a concrete type also wouldn't work
        let hash = T::Hash::default();
     }:{
 Signatures::<T>::insert(hash, custom);
}
```

}
it gives me the following error:

```
 error[E0277]: the trait bound `frame_support::BoundedBTreeMap<sp_core::sr25519::Public, frame_support::BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<64>>, ConstU32<32>>: EncodeL
ike<frame_support::BoundedBTreeMap<sp_core::sr25519::Public, frame_support::BoundedVec<u8, <T as pallet::Config>::SignatureLength>, <T as pallet::Config>::
MaxAuthorities>>` is not satisfied
     --> /home/test/projects/custom/pallet/src/benchmarking.rs:70:46
      |
  70  |             Signatures::<T>::insert(hash, custom);
      |             ----------------------           ^^^^^^ the trait `EncodeLike<frame_support::BoundedBTreeMap<sp_core::sr25519::Public, frame_support::Bou
ndedVec<u8, <T as pallet::Config>::SignatureLength>, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxAuthorities>>` is not implemented for `frame_support::BoundedBTreeMap<sp_cor
e::sr25519::Public, frame_support::BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<64>>, ConstU32<32>>`
```

even though the same code is executed perfectly in the pallet with no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using `ConstU32<64>` instead of the config constant `T::SignatureLength` (same for the other parameter). It is not correct and lead to problems when benchmarking your pallet later on.
For the hash type: you need to require it to have a `Default` in the config trait and then do `T::Hash::default()`. You can obviously not use concrete types here, since benchmarks are generic over the pallet config trait. But you could additionally require them to be `From<H256>` for benchmarking only by putting a `where_clause` on the benchmark.

In your case you can probably let the Rust compiler guess the type like this:

```rust
benchmarks!{
test_add{
        let mut custom = BoundedBTreeMap::new();
        let id = H256::default();// using a concrete type also wouldn't work
        let hash = T::Hash::default();
     }:{
 Signatures::<T>::insert(hash, custom);
}
```

Or if you really want to type it, then create a type alias with something like `SignatureOf<T>` for example like in the [Alliance](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a507125d796760b21d433681cbf8a5d0ec2132d7/frame/alliance/src/lib.rs#L130-L131) pallet and use that.
If this does not answer your question the please provide source code. Otherwise it is not possible to debug.

Comment: it actually worked by removing the type though i remember it was complaining in the begining about the type not been know so i had to specify it, also using T::SignatureLength wont work, it says `use of generic parameter from outer function`